# Frame ID dynamic changes - how can collect those id selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

This is a sales force application, i want to do an action in the grid and the gird located inside the frame, so first i switch to the frame.

But frame id changed dynamically for every load

samples:

```
<iframe id="vfFrameId_1488964056725" class="" name="vfFrameId_1488964056725" scrolling="yes" data-aura-rendered-by="32:3171;a" allowfullscreen="true" title="Profiles ~ Salesforce - Developer Edition" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">

<iframe id="vfFrameId_1488964240739" class="" name="vfFrameId_1488964240739" scrolling="yes" data-aura-rendered-by="32:3394;a" allowfullscreen="true" title="Profiles ~ Salesforce - Developer Edition" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">

<iframe id="vfFrameId_1488965139825" class="" name="vfFrameId_1488965139825" scrolling="yes" data-aura-rendered-by="32:4068;a" allowfullscreen="true" title="Profiles ~ Salesforce - Developer Edition" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
```

Each time the frame id dynamically changed, so how can i switch into this frame. i struggled the below action

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='vfFrameId_1488962229939']")));
        this.userIndexSletter.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to handle dynamic `id`:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'vfFrameId_')]")));
```

This should allow to use only constant part of `id`

Also you can use `title` attribute:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='Profiles ~ Salesforce - Developer Edition']")));
```